# After certain string is found mark every after string as true,pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = pd.Series({0: 'registration address-complement-insert-confirmation input',
 1: 'decision-tree first-interaction-validation options',
 2: 'decision-tree invalid-format-validation options',
 3: 'decision-tree first-interaction-validation options',
 4: 'registration address-complement-request view',
 5: 'onboarding return-start origin',
 6: 'registration address-complement-request origin',
 7: 'decision-tree identified-regex options',
 8: 'decision-tree first-interaction-validation options',
 9: 'decision-tree first-interaction-validation options'})
```

I have the following series object. What I want to do is to map it and mark every single string after 'onboarding return-start origin' as true. Any ideas on how I could build this condition?

Wanted result

```
s = pd.Series({0: False,
 1: False,
 2: False,
 3: False,
 4: False,
 5: True,
 6: True,
 7: True,
 8: True,
 9: True})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with test first matched value by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
s = s.eq('onboarding return-start origin').cummax()
print (s)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Ah fudge, yes False = 0 True = 1. GODAMMIT python 101 again

Comment: Out of curiosity if I had to use this on a groupby object, how would you do the statement?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 - Then use `df['col'].eq('onboarding return-start origin').groupby(df['group']).cummax()`