# Optimization of map, in grouped by object

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 'product-availability address-confirmation input',
  1: 'registration register-data-confirmation options',
  2: 'onboarding return-start input',
  3: 'registration register-data-confirmation input',
  4: 'decision-tree first-interaction-validation options'},
 'Original_UserId': {0: '5511949551865@wa.gw.msging.net',
  1: '5511949551865@wa.gw.msging.net',
  2: '5511949551865@wa.gw.msging.net',
  3: '5511949551865@wa.gw.msging.net',
  4: '5511949551865@wa.gw.msging.net'}})
```

Thank to jezrael I am applying the following map, which follows the logic given in this question [After certain string is found mark every after string as true,pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75285136/after-certain-string-is-found-mark-every-after-string-as-true-pandas/75285152?noredirect=1#comment132846602_75285152)

```
test_df.groupby('Original_UserId',observed=True)['Category'].apply(lambda s : s.eq('onboarding return-start input').cummax())
```

Which returns the following series

```
pd.Series({0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True})
```

The thing is when I apply this condition, to a larger dataset it takes quite a while to run this code. Any clues on how to optimize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compare column `Category` and then use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) per column `Original_UserId`:

```
s = (test_df['Category'].eq('onboarding return-start input')
                        .groupby(test_df['Original_UserId'],observed=True)
                        .cummax())
print (s)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: Category, dtype: bool
```

Another idea is create helper column:

```
s = (test_df.assign(tmp = test_df['Category'].eq('onboarding return-start input'))
            .groupby('Original_UserId',observed=True)['tmp']
            .cummax())
print (s)
```

Comment: Don't you think you should update your previous answer and closed this as a dupe (just for `observed=True`)? :-)

Comment: @Corralien - previous answer was not per groups.

Comment: Your last comment: """@INGl0R1AM0R1 - Then use df['col'].eq('onboarding return-start origin').groupby(df['group']).cummax()"""

Comment: @Corralien - I add answer because in this question is not used my solution from comment.

Comment: I dont get the first solution, isnt the parameter df['col'] inside the groupby syntactic sugar, according to pandas?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 exactly you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `multiprocessing` if your dataframe is large and avoid to use `Dask` or `PySpark`:

```
def f(s):
    return s.eq('onboarding return-start input').cummax()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test_df = ...
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        groups = test_df.groupby('Original_UserId',observed=True)['Category']
        data = pool.map(f, [g for _, g in groups])
    s = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> s
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: Category, dtype: bool
```